# How to pass id parameter to .ashx file upload

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

Hi i have this Ocap ID which is auto generated id from DB sequence and i have this file upload using jquery ajax [my reference of file upload](http://lateshtclick.com/blogpost/uploading-files-using-jquery-ajax-and-generic-handler-ashx-in-aspnet#:%7E:text=We%20will%20use%20UploadHandler.,upload%20files%20on%20server%20side.&text=Now%20run%20your%20application%20that,and%20click%20on%20Upload%20files.) ,I want to insert to database the file path and the Ocap ID `$('#ocapID').val()`
in the .ashx file but how can i pass the Ocap ID to the .ashx file

i've search the internet but i'm not sure what to look for.

Hope someone help me out with this thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

My sample code like this. It will return a object with property Id and Name.

**javascript with jquery**

```js
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Handler1.ashx',
        data: { itemId : 100 },
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                alert(data.Name);
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

***handler ashx***

```cs
public class Handler1 : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string szItemId = context.Request.QueryString["itemId"] ?? string.Empty;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(szItemId)) return;

        int nItemId = -999;
        if (!int.TryParse(szItemId, out nItemId) || nItemId <= 0) return;

        Student stu = new Student(nItemId);

        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.Charset = "utf-8";
        context.Response.Write(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(stu));
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

public class Student
{
    public Student(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = "Test";
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```